# Training the Variational Autoencoder After applying the reparameterization trick

Tags: deep-learning, training, autoencoder

In a Variational Autoencoders, z cannot be simply sampled from the output of the autoencoder directly since the network would not be differentiable. Instead, we have to sample from a normal distribution who's parameters are the output of the autoencoder, mu and stddev.

I So cannot understand how the network isn't differentiable (lets say we take z = mu + srd). So the reparameterization is not clear to me.

Any help would be much appreciated!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you read Doersch's [tutorial on VAE](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1606.05908.pdf)? In paragraph 1.1 the author shows main intuitions behind the latent model and in the following sections he goes deeper into the explanation of how a VAE works. I think it's a good starting point to approach to VAEs.